# Identification of ライヤ: 来夜、来耶、来也 and its meaning

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

I do not know what is the correct word for ライヤ in the song 雷火ライヤ from Stella Glow, nor its meaning.

There are 2 sources that give the title of the song:

> - [雷火{らいか}来耶{ライヤ}](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/nm26475768)
> - [雷火{らいか}来夜{ライヤ}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF08XFj0sdI)

Also up for consideration is 来也 from [自来也](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiraiya).

---

Here are the lyrics from the first stanza:

> 歌えや雷火ライヤ、おどれや雷火ライヤ
>   拍手と喝采の波さえ愛紡ぐ
>   怒りも雷火ライヤ、力よ雷火ライヤ
>   祭り囃子煽り立てよ、巡りあう星たちを
>   全て武器にして猛る心で
>   熱き疾風となってこの空駆けるや

And the corresponding lines involving ライヤ for the next stanza:

> - 浮かれや雷火ライヤ、騒げや雷火ライヤ... ...
> - 祈れや雷火ライヤ、讃えや雷火ライヤ... ...

---

Thoughts for 来夜:

- The English title is "Fiery Night".
- But would it not simply be 雷火夜 then? What does 来 add to this apart from musical metre/rhythm?

Thoughts for 來也:

- There exists 自来也 which possibly comes from 我来也 , which I understand as "I am come" as an archaic expression (much like the grammar in the Christmas carol lyric "Joy to the world, the Lord **is come**")
- In this sense I imagine 雷火来也 to mean "Fire is come" with archaic tones.

I have no arguments for 来耶 except that it be a variant of 來也.

**What is the correct word in the lyrics, and what does it mean?**

Comment: One point: using 也 in the end usually suggests a male name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't the think kanji-level analysis is that meaningful, because らいや sounds to me like just a not-so-rare person name.

Anyway, from what I could google [Both 来夜 and 来耶 seem to be typo, and 來夜 is the correct spelling](https://youtu.be/dMpU0mdnm-8?t=3m28s). (來 is an old form of 来)

[image]

[The person who wrote this song](http://blog.zaq.ne.jp/ayune/article/98/) says it's 雷火**來夜**, too. Literally it just means "upcoming night", of course, but I don't know the implication.

---

**EDIT:** The lyricist explains how 雷火來夜 was invented. She even clearly states 来耶 is a typo :-)

> かけ声のような言葉を多用して盛り上がる感じにしてほしい、とのことだったので、火の魔女らしくて響きのイイ呪文のような音を探していくうち、閃いたのが「雷火」という言葉、「ライカライカ？」→「ライカライヤ！」でした。
>   これなら和風の造語にして、「来たる夜」の意味を込めたいなと「雷火來夜」に決めました。「雷火来耶」という表記がたまにあるけど、難しいほうの「來」に「夜」の表記になります^^*